# How to define WCF End Point in Azure function?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-functions, azure-relay

I have been working with this solution where A client application is supposed to access WCF service via Relay.

I have followed this tutorial and was able to access WCF service hosted in console app with client console app.

What I want to achieve is, To access WCF service hosted in local machine via a function app.

So I migrated the code which i did in client console app as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial#example-code-for-this-tutorial) to the azure function app.

The client console app had a config file as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial#example-of-the-appconfig-file)

I have 2 doubts

I have two doubts.

**1)** I can not understand how to define endpoint in azure function app which was defined in App.Config file in case of console app as below.

```
<client>
      <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"
                      contract="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples.IEchoContract"
                      binding="netTcpRelayBinding"/>
    </client>
```

**2)** Is there any way to dynamically define endpoint right in the code of function app?

```
  log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;

            string serviceNamespace = "MyTestRelay";
            string sasKey = "mpQKrfJ6L4Ftdsds2v6Leg3X0e9+Q8MOfjxwghj7xk2qSA=";


            Uri serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "EchoService");
            TransportClientEndpointBehavior sasCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
            sasCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", sasKey);

            DynamicEndpoint dynamicEndpoint = new DynamicEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IEchoContract)), new WSHttpBinding() );
```

//I AM GETTING ERROR IN Below Line

```
            ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>("RelayEndpoint", new EndpointAddress(serviceUri));

            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sasCredential);

            IEchoChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter text to echo (or [Enter] to exit):");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server echoed: {0}", channel.Echo(input));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            channel.Close();
            channelFactory.Close();
```

Can anyone suggest how to work with this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: My guess would be that you're not passing a Binding to your ChannelFactory... You create the DynamicEndpoint with WSHttpBinding but then don't reference it again.

Comment: @stuartd : the error I'm getting is endpoint not defined

Comment: @joehoper : Exactly, I want to pass the binding in C# code to the relay like there is  <client>
      <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"
                      contract="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples.IEchoContract"
                      binding="netTcpRelayBinding"/>
    </client> present in my current console app where it works fine. But here i don't have app.config so where to pass it in c# code

Comment: There are [overloads to CreateChannel that accept a binding as one of the parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channelfactory-1.createchannel?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating bindings in code maps to the XML in app.config and you can use like so:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
var binding = new NetTcpRelayBinding()
{
     // Example properties that might be in your app.config
     ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
     SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
};

var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>(binding, endpoint);
```

Comment: Thanks !! But Even after providing binding, It's showing same Error. Maybe because binding has been created but this part is not configured dynamically                                               <client>
      <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"
                      contract="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples.IEchoContract"
                      binding="netTcpRelayBinding"/>
    </client>

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to show how you’ve changed it?  You’ll have to remove all references to named endpoints and bindings like RelayEndpoint etc

Comment: It was my mistake, I forgot to enable the service and that's why it was showing endpoint issue. Your solution worked. Thank you so much Sir !!!